# lenovo g480 blank screen while booting ubuntu

Tags: installation, boot, lenovo

i love Ubuntu very much but i cant install it on my laptop whenever i try to boot it form CD the screen just went blank and DVD spins so fast like its installing to many files but it was some sort of problem.i try it so many times but it didn't worked. 
please help me

thanks in advance

Shahzad

Comment: It would be the writing errors. At what speed did you burn your DVD? Have you tired to install using boot-able USB?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it (at least partially) by turning up the brightness on the screen.
I do not know why the computer automatically sets it to zero when starting ubuntu.
Anyway, just try it.